# GSL and gsl_linalg_cholesky_invert

Tags: c, compiler-errors, statistics, syntax-error, blas

I'm using the gsl library in a c code. Everything goes fine but when i use the command gsl_linalg_cholesky_invert the terminal shows the following message:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:"_gsl_linalg_cholesky_invert", referenced from:
  _main in cc4eefuQ.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

A code example is the following.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_math.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_linalg.h>
#include <math.h>

void main()
{
gsl_matrix * A      = gsl_matrix_calloc (2,2);

gsl_matrix_set(A,0,0,1);
gsl_matrix_set(A,0,1,0.5);
gsl_matrix_set(A,1,0,0.5);
gsl_matrix_set(A,1,1,1);
gsl_linalg_cholesky_decomp(A);
gsl_linalg_cholesky_invert(A);
}
```

If i comment out the line `gsl_linalg_cholesky_invert(A);`, everything goes fine.

I compile the code with the following command:

```
gcc-mp-4.7 wrapnorm.c -o wrapnorm -lgsl -l gslcblas -lm
```

with  a macbook pro with mountain lion and gsl version 1.9.

Thanks